# Get position pressing headerRight in react-native

Tags: react-native

How can I get the position when I click on one of the button in the headerRight in react native ? I tried following the documentation but it's not displaying anything. Here is the code :

```
static navigationOptions = {
    headerRight: (
      <View style={{marginLeft: 8, marginRight: 8, flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center' }}>
        <TouchableOpacity style={{ marginRight: 10 }} onPress={ () =>{ }}>
            <Image style={{ width: 22, height: 22 }} source={require("../Images/search.png")} />
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity style={{marginLeft: 10, marginRight: 10 }} onPress={ () =>{ this.displayPosition()}}>
            <Image style={{ width: 22, height: 22 }} source={require("../Images/localisation.png")} />
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity style={{marginLeft: 10 }} onPress={ () =>{ }}>
            <Image style={{ width: 22, height: 22 }} source={require("../Images/refresh.png")} />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    ),
  };

displayPosition(){
    Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
      (position) => {
        this.setState({
          latitude: position.coords.latitude,
          longitude: position.coords.longitude,
          error: null,
        });
      },
      (error) => this.setState({ error: error.message }),
      { enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 20000, maximumAge: 1000 },
    );
     Alert.alert(this.state.latitude, this.state.longitude)
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please clarify, Are you trying to get the (lat, long) position from geolocation or simply the item position from headerRight?

Comment: I'm trying to get the Latitude and longitude position

Comment: Try doing it like this - "latitude: JSON.stringify(position.coords.latitude)"

Comment: I've tried but it's not rendering anything. The `displayPosition()` content works when I tried to just display inside a `<Text>` component. But when I try to display an alert when I press the icon in my header then nothing happen

Answer (score 0):

assuming that you refer button with location image, i think it would be better if your code follow this stranded when calling the function `onPress`.

```
<TouchableOpacity style={{ marginLeft: 10, marginRight: 10 }} onPress={ this.displayPosition}>
   <Image style={{ width: 22, height: 22 }} source={require("../Images/localisation.png")} />
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Also, make sure to bind the `displayPosition()` in constrocter

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            // your State
        };
        this.displayPosition = this.displayPosition.bind(this);
    }
```

and make it a arrow function.

`displayPosition = () => { \\ Your code}`